# SQL Server LocalDB errors ("parent instance invalid")

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, localdb

I installed SQL Server 2012 local db [from this download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

choosing `ENU\x64\SqlLocalDB.MSI`

I ran it OK, then tried to use the `sqllocaldb` command, I got this error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb
```

> Start of LocalDB instance "mssqllocaldb" failed because of the following error:
>   Unexpected error occurred inside a LocalDB instance API method call.
>   See the Windows Application event log for error details.

The log says this:

> Windows API call RegOpenKeyExW returned error code: 2. Windows system error message is: The system cannot find the file specified. Reported at line: 967.

and

> LocalDB parent instance version is invalid: MSSQL12E.LOCALDB

and

> Windows API call GetSvcBinPathByInstName returned error code: 2. Windows system error message is: The system cannot find the file specified. Reported at line: 3546.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed it by deleting the instance and recreating it:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqllocaldb delete mssqllocaldb
LocalDB instance "mssqllocaldb" deleted.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqllocaldb create mssqllocaldb
LocalDB instance "mssqllocaldb" created with version 11.0.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqllocaldb i
mssqllocaldb
v11.0
```

Comment: I have similar problem when i uninstall the LocalDB 2016 and install its 2017 version. after upgrade, I got similar error. I think it could be due to not removing the previous MSSQLLocalDB instance before uninstalling older localdb version. the solution provided here works!

Comment: I have the same problem, but this does not work for me.  I get the same message when I try to delete it